# Multiple instances of jQuery UI auto complete

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm working on a project where I need to have several instances (with different XML-files) of a modified jQuery UI autocomplete script, which make it possible to fetch info from an XML-file.

The jsfiddle doesn't work because the XML-files isn't there. But it's a good overview:
See code here http://jsfiddle.net/ua6mN/

#### Cities.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cities>
    <city label="Copenhagen" value="CPH" country="DK" />
    <city label="Paris" value="PRS" country="FR" />
    <city label="Miami" value="MI" country="US" />
</cities>
```

#### States.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<states>
    <state label="Alabama" value="AL" country="US" />
    <state label="Alaska" value="AK" country="US" />
    <state label="Arkansas" value="AR" country="US" />
    <state label="Arizona" value="AZ" country="US" />
    <state label="California" value="CA" country="US" />
    <state label="Colorado" value="CO" country="US" />
    <state label="Connecticut" value="CT" country="US" />
    <state label="District of Columbia" value="DC" country="US" />
    <state label="Delaware" value="DE" country="US" />
    <state label="Florida" value="FL" country="US" />
    <state label="Georgia" value="GA" country="US" />
    <state label="Hawaii" value="HI" country="US" />
    <state label="Idaho" value="ID" country="US" />
    <state label="Illinois" value="IL" country="US" />
    <state label="Indiana" value="IN" country="US" />
    <state label="Iowa" value="IA" country="US" />
    <state label="Kansas" value="KS" country="US" />
    <state label="Kentucky" value="KY" country="US" />
    <state label="Louisiana" value="LA" country="US" />
    <state label="Maine" value="ME" country="US" />
    <state label="Maryland" value="MD" country="US" />
    <state label="Massachusetts" value="MA" country="US" />
    <state label="Michigan" value="MI" country="US" />
    <state label="Minnesota" value="MN" country="US" />
    <state label="Mississippi" value="MS" country="US" />
    <state label="Missouri" value="MO" country="US" />
    <state label="Montana" value="MT" country="US" />
    <state label="Nebraska" value="NE" country="US" />
    <state label="Nevada" value="NV" country="US" />
    <state label="New Hampshire" value="NH" country="US" />
    <state label="New Jersey" value="NJ" country="US" />
    <state label="New Mexico" value="NM" country="US" />
    <state label="New York" value="NY" country="US" />
    <state label="North Carolina" value="NC" country="US" />
    <state label="North Dakota" value="ND" country="US" />
    <state label="Ohio" value="OH" country="US" />
    <state label="Oklahoma" value="OK" country="US" />
    <state label="Oregon" value="OR" country="US" />
    <state label="Pennsylvania" value="PA" country="US" />
    <state label="Rhode Island" value="RI" country="US" />
    <state label="South Carolina" value="SC" country="US" />
    <state label="South Dakota" value="SD" country="US" />
    <state label="Tennessee" value="TN" country="US" />
    <state label="Texas" value="TX" country="US" />
    <state label="Utah" value="UT" country="US" />
    <state label="Vermont" value="VT" country="US" />
    <state label="Virginia" value="VA" country="US" />
    <state label="Washington" value="WA" country="US" />
    <state label="West Virginia" value="WV" country="US" />
    <state label="Wisconsin" value="WI" country="US" />
    <state label="Wyoming" value="WY" country="US" />
</states>
```

I tried a bunch of stuff, but I couldn't make it work... :-( Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Use unique ids for autocomplete input fields. In your jsfiddle example, both of your input fields use the same id="searchState". Use `$("#searchCity").autocomplete({...});` and `$("#searchState").autocomplete({...});` instead.

Comment: Hi vls. It will still be the same XML-file. I have changed the IDs now. Do you know how to get info from two xml-files with two autocompletes??

Comment: Kenneth: Yea, you can load your XML data using jQuery.get() into 2 separate data structures and then point autocomplete source parameter to them.